# ASP.NET MVC 4 C# Failed Connected Ajax Post With Model

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm making an AAX request using jQuery, post like this:

```
$("#frm").submit(function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/My/Controller/Action",
        type: "POST",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (status) {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

and here my controller :

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult QuizCalculation()
{
    foreach (string keys in Response.Form.AllKeys)
    {
        var m = db.Quiz.Single(h => h.id == keys);
    }

    Request.AcceptTypes.Contains("application/json");
    return Json(new { status = true });
}
```

But it always returns an error :

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'string'

in part `=> h.id == keys`

Please help me. Any idea on what is causing this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to either convert `id` to a string, or `keys` to an `int`. Try this:

```
foreach (string keys in Response.Form.AllKeys)
{
    var m = db.Quiz.Single(h => h.id.ToString() == keys);
}
```

Or this:

```
foreach (string keys in Response.Form.AllKeys)
{
    var m = db.Quiz.Single(h => h.id == Int16.Parse(keys));
}
```

Also, you should look in to using ModelBinding to receive your parameters, instead of looping through the `Form`.